# Toast message not displayed at x seconds in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, handler, android-toast

I want to show a toast message every 2 second in my application which is in fragment not activity.

But in my code it show only once I share my code below.

Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false); 


    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

    mMapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    mMapView.onCreate(mBundle); 


    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() 
        .permitAll().build(); 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    } 

    /* new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
    setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); */

     handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
                setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); 

             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Updated!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.e("Data in Log", "");
        }
    }, 1000);

    new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
    setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);

    /*LocationManager locman = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //locman.requestLocationUpdates(minTime, minDistance, criteria, intent);
    locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);*/

    return rootView; 
}
```

Comment: Your thread will run only once..The correct method is one given by JohanShogun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It work for me, you can these code...

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("run", "run");

                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 60000, 60000);
```

these code is run after every 1Min..

Comment: Down voted for use of legacy API. Google recommends using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for new code: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: @ULHAS PATIL:Can you please tell me what is the purpose of giving 60000 two times ???

Comment: @user3631500 it is milliseconds, it takes time in milliseconds so 1000 = 1sec. and 60000 = 1 min.
It will run after that time i.e. after 1Min.

Comment: But i think you must listen of @JohanShogun because i put my old code up there, i think you should try "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" as he write there, it is Google Recommends, so go with it if it works as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

postDelayed only does something once, easiest solution for you is just to repost the task like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable repeatingToast = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "My text!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         if(your_condition) {
             handler.postDelayed(repeatingToast, 1000);
         }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(repeatingToast, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your code is run only once that's why after 1sec. it shows that toast message. So make sure your code is running again and again. Did you see your log again and again?

Comment: Actually I need to call a method continuously in every x seconds so first am checking with toast message ,can you please tell me  how to call a method in every x seconds

Comment: So you have to use Timer for that. Please use Google and check about Timer. It may help you as per your requirement

Comment: Timers schedule one-shot or recurring tasks for execution. Prefer ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for new code. Your just repost the runnable like I showed below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.LENGTH_LONG = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

So you are calling next Toast before 1st one is dismissing.Try a longer duration in the thread.